# Failed to parse the output of 'adb version'

Tags: android, eclipse, ubuntu, sdk, adb

I'm using Ubuntu 11.10 and Eclipse for android developing. I've already made a new project, but it contains error:

```
Failed to parse the output of 'adb version'
```

I will be thankful if anyone have an idea how can I fix that?

Answer (score 3):

1. Install Oracle JRE using PPA:

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ferramroberto/java
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install sun-java6-jre sun-java6-plugin sun-java6-fonts
   ```
2. Install ia32-libs from software center.

Answer (score 1):

Two options to solve this problem on windows:
Option 1:

1. Close the eclipse, if it is running.
2. Run the command prompt.
3. Go to the tools location of the android sdk.
4. run 'adb kill-server'
5. then run 'adb start-server'.
6. start the eclipse.

Option 2:

1. Open the task manager.
2. kill the adb process.
3. start the eclipse.

Problem should be solved.

Comment: where should i run adb kill-server exactly?it doesnot work in ubuntu terminal.

Comment: and there is no adb process in system monitor.

Comment: from terminal first go to your tools path and type the command.

Comment: in linux u cant run your code separately ..and there no command exist in linux like adb start-server and all that

Comment: thanks for this solution, it works like a charm for me on windows 7x64

Answer (score 1):

The official Android SDK only runs on i386 JVM, so you need to manually specify the i386 JVM on Eclipse.

1. First install the <strike>Sun</strike>(Oracle) 32-bit JVM. [Here is](http://brunoreis.com/tech/intalling-java-ubuntu-natty/) a step-by-step on how to do this:
2. Add the JVM to Eclipse. Navigate:

   ```
   Window > Preferences > Java > Installed JREs > Add
   ```

   Put the location of the JVM. Probably will be `/usr/lib/jvm/java7/` (my is `/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-sun-1.7.0.01`). The external libraries will be *automatically* added when you put the location of the JVM.
    [image: Java7 Add Eclipse]
3. Set the <strike>Sun</strike> (Oracle) 32-bit JVM as default.
    [image: Java7 Default Eclipse]

Answer (score 0):

if you run eclipse immediately after installing your java JDK, the java virtual machine MIGHT not be properly started.  you will receive this error code when launching eclipse.

first check if when you installed your JDK, you copied a script file

> /etc/init.d/jexec

if you did, before you do anything fancy, reboot your machine so that jvm starts properly.  if you didnt, please decompress your jdk rpm file and extract the contents properly and then reboot.

worked for me, i just had this problem while installing adt bundle (and java jdk) on a virgin install of ubuntu 12.04 on a 64bit machine.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the platform tools and then re-install them from the SDK manager

Answer (score 0):

Copy the sdk\platform-tools contents to sdk\tool 
also you must have a JAVA_HOME env var pointing to your java location 
ex. JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21