# Failed to parse the output of 'adb version' with android sdk and eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator, android-2.2-froyo

Hi I am trying to install android sdk with eclipse but it keeps showing this error to me

"Failed to parse the output of 'adb version'"

I followed following links but could not work for me

[Failed to parse the output of 'adb version'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8415034/failed-to-parse-the-output-of-adb-version)

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1001858

[Failed to parse the output of 'adb version'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2260118/failed-to-parse-the-output-of-adb-version)

[Eclipse/adb error message in Vista "Failed to parse the output of adb version"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2994062/eclipse-adb-error-message-in-vista-failed-to-parse-the-output-of-adb-version)

Any solution please.

Comment: Hi, would be nice to know which version of Eclipse you are using, which version of the SDK and of the JDK.

Moreover, are you local administrator of your PC or you have limited privileges on the machine? If so, which is your access level/rights?

Comment: I am using the latest versions of Eclipse and SDK since I downloaded them a while ago. I am using jre not JDK. Yes I am local admin of my PC.

Comment: Now I installed JDK as well but still the same problem.

Comment: I downloaded the SDK from this link http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html . Now I installed JDK as well but still the same problem.

Comment: Now it also shows these errors: DDMS files not found: D:\eclipse\platform-tools\adb.exe D:\eclipse\tools\hprof-conv.exe D:\eclipse\tools\traceview.bat

Comment: Now again back to the same error: Failed to parse the output of 'adb version'              The rest of the errors are gone.

Comment: in your windows.env settings android sdk installer should have put some tool paths in your system path and you should have an ANDROID_SDK_HOME pointing to the SDK DMMS files not found bu its trying to locate the android sdk tool sin your eclipse install ie other words are you missing the ANDROID_SDK_HOME in windwos env settings

Comment: My SDK is installed at D:\android-sdk-windows and my eclipse is installed at D:\eclipse. Here are my environment variables set ups %SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\Python27\;C:\Python27\Scripts\;C:\Ruby192\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\haml-3.1.3;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin\java.exe;C:\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools\adb.exe;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_02\bin

Comment: anyone who can help me? I am still stuck

Comment: I am using eclipse indigo version. Anyone who can help please.

Comment: Hi man, it looks to me an local anti virus problem locking the required sys resources. Try to temporary disable or remove it if there is one . Let us know.

Comment: Thanks Maurizio Benedetti. I disabled my antivirus completely and it works now. Thanks again :-)

Answer (score 1):

In my case disabling firewall for a while solves the problem. Firewall probably had blocked adb, so add it to "trusted programs".